# Keras: Multiple outputs, one output as input in the same network

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I have a neural network with two outputs, the second output has the first output as input.

I guess during the training the first output's weights will be trained twice. Is that ok?
Is there some way to prevent output one will be trained from the output two?

Here an example, output one is an action and the second output is a subaction that depend of input and the first action.

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(2, ))

# Create the first output
output_1_action = Dense(10)(input_tensor)

# Create the second output(use the first output as input here)
x = Concatenate([input_tensor, output_1_action])
output_2_subaction = Dense(10)(x)

# Create a model with 2 outputs
model = Model(input_tensor, [output_1_action, output_2_subaction])
```

For this simple example I can use two networks but my model uses lstm layers and I want to keep one state and one neural network.

Answer (score 0):

i can't exactly understand what you are trying to do, but through a custom training loop, you can achieve every possible thing and Tensorflow will automatically graph the gradients for you. If you want a more exact solution, please elaborate more on your model.

```
def train_step():
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      out1, out2 = model(data)

      out3, out4 = model(out1)

      loss = tf.keras.losses.mse(...)

  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```